# How to color bars who make up 50% of the data?

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting a histogram for some data points with bar heights being the percentage of that bin from the whole data:

```
x = normal(size=1000)
hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=20)
plt.bar(bins[:-1], hist.astype(np.float32) / hist.sum(), width=(bins[1]-bins[0]), alpha=0.6)
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like all bars that sum up to be 50% of the data to be in a different color, for example:

[image]

(I selected the colored bars without actually checking whether their sum adds to 50%)

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: please paste the code you already used.

Comment: The second image is a mockup :/ I don't have code for it...

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can plot the first half of the bins with a different color, this looks like your mock, but I am not sure it complies to %50 of the data (it is not clear to me what do you mean by that).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 50, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)


# now that we found the index we color all the beans smaller than middle index
for p in patches[:len(bins)/2]:
    p.set_facecolor('red')
    
# hist uses np.histogram under the hood to create 'n' and 'bins'.
# np.histogram returns the bin edges, so there will be 50 probability
# density values in n, 51 bin edges in bins and 50 patches.  To get
# everything lined up, we'll compute the bin centers
bincenters = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])
# add a 'best fit' line for the normal PDF
y = mlab.normpdf( bincenters, mu, sigma)
l = ax.plot(bincenters, y, 'r--', linewidth=1)

ax.set_xlabel('Smarts')
ax.set_ylabel('Probability')
ax.set_xlim(40, 160)
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.03)
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

And the output is:

[image]

## update

The key method you want to look at is `patch.set_facecolor`. You have to understand that almost everything you plot inside the axes object is a Patch, and as such it has this method. Here is another example, I arbitrarily choose the first 3 bars to have another color, you can choose based on what ever you decide:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

## the data
N = 5
menMeans = [18, 35, 30, 35, 27]

## necessary variables
ind = np.arange(N)                # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35                      # the width of the bars

## the bars
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width,
                color='black',
                error_kw=dict(elinewidth=2,ecolor='red'))

for patch in rects1.patches[:3]:
    patch.set_facecolor('red')    

ax.set_xlim(-width,len(ind)+width)
ax.set_ylim(0,45)
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
xTickMarks = ['Group'+str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
ax.set_xticks(ind)
xtickNames = ax.set_xticklabels(xTickMarks)
plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=45, fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. In my diagram each bar stands for the percentage of points in the data that correspond to that value. I would like all bars that sum up to be 50% of the data points to be in a different color. I tried modifying your code but I can't seem to find a way to normalize the bars to represent the percentage of the data (normed=1 doesn't seem to do that)

Comment: like I said before, put here what ever you coded so it will be possible to help you. Right now, it's just guessing.

Comment: Sorry not sure to what other code you are referring to? The only code that I have is provided in the question...

Comment: I am asking again, what do you mean by 50% of the data point? If you have 20 points, then 50 percent is up to the 10th point, if you mean cumulative sum, there is also a way, but your not so specific.

Comment: 50% from the data points, if the first bar in the histogram represent a bin with 4 points, the next with 5, and the 3rd with 11, and those three bars would be colored, the rest will be in the default color.

Comment: `ax.hist(...,normed=1,...)` is deprecated, use `ax.hist(...,density=True,...)`