# add text in bins of histogram in wxpython

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, wxpython

How to write text inside bins(bars) of histograms in wxpython?

```
    import csv
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    data1 = np.random.normal(5.0,3.0,1000)
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)



    plt.hist(data1)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't write text inside the bins directly. This is because the bins are simple Pactch objects.
However, have no despair! There is a path you can go to achieve this:

- iterate over bins, get their boundaries
- create a text label
- place it in the correct boundaries

To obtain the bin boundaries see my answer here: [How to color bars who make up 50% of the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227883/how-to-color-bars-who-make-up-50-of-the-data)

Comment: sir,using the label how will i write vertical text in bins??